# Can you call a contract's (C) function with the msg.sender value of another contract (B) while originating the transaction from a third contract (A)?

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development

If there exists a proxy/implementation system (two contract system) where Contract C (the proxy) only accepts calls from Contract B (Contract B is the owner of Contract C via {owner = msg.sender} in the constructor of contract C), could a third contract, Contract A *that is also the owner of Contract B*, call Contract C with a msg.sender value that is equal to Contract B (and thus be able to use the proxy's functions because to the proxy it is being called by its owner)?

Additionally, is there any way that A can call C with the identity of B? What if B does not have an explicit function to do so?

Any help here would be greatly appreciated. I am trying to wrap my head around the various calls/interactions between contracts. Is this achievable with a special type of call?

Comment: `What if B does not have an explicit function to do so?` - then you can't do that.

Comment: @goodvibration thanks for your reply! Additionally, do you think there is anyway that A could write to B's storage even if there is not an explicit function to do so (but A is the owner/has authority privileges of B)?

Comment: Ask yourself what does `is the owner/has authority privileges of` really mean in technical terms...